# Is the optimal binary code for these frequencies unambiguous?

Tags: binary-search-tree, huffman-code

i should create a Huffman code with this frequencies  1300, 1900, 2000, 2400,
3000, 3300, 3400, 3900, 4900, 7000, 7200, 9900.

[MySolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7G9Y.jpg)

My Question is the optimal binary code for these frequencies unambiguous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tree is unambiguous, since there are no ties for which bottom two frequencies to add at each step. However the binary codes are certainly not unambiguous. You don't have to assign 0 to the left and 1 to the right. You can swap those for any subset of the eleven nodes you like, resulting in 2048 different optimal binary codes.

Comment: "However the binary codes are certainly not ambiguous." Do you mean the binary codes are unambiguous?

Comment: Should be not unambiguous. Fixed.